# 4 quadrant pie chart in android

Tags: android, achartengine

Hi Can anyone help me with any links or hints on how I can achieve the following.

I need to be able to plot lines based on the touch event by the user from the center of a pie chart/circular image. I am a little familiar with aChartEngine, but not able to figure out how I can do it. I also need to store the XY co-ordinates so that I can reproduce it at a later point in time (the graph/image size will be different). So my XY points from the touch events should be from the center of the graph/image. Any leads/hints/links will be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you need. Please post some screenshots or something for explaining better.